# Facebook v2 api taggable friends api returns null list when testing

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am the administrator of the app so I should be able to test it without approval, correct?  The status & review section says this for taggable friends...

> By default, you may only call the Taggable Friends API for people who are listed in the Roles section of your app's Dashboard. This is to allow you to develop and test your integration. If you want to use the Taggable Friends API in a public version of your app, you must submit this feature for review.

```
 if (response.status === 'connected') {
  // Logged into your app and Facebook.
  testAPI();
  getFriends(response.authResponse.accessToken);
} ... 
function getFriends(token) {
  FB.api("/me/taggable_friends", function(res) {
  console.log("friends", res);

  });
}
```

Not sure what I'm missing here.  Thanks

Comment: Have you granted user_friends permission to the app?

Comment: isn't that granted by default?

Comment: No, you have to ask for any permission you want to use

Comment: Hmm, under approved items in status & review tab it lists user_friends under Approved login permissions.  I havent yet sumbitted this app for review, i just want to test locally

Comment: Doesn't matter if is approved or not. You need to ask the user for permission

Comment: As of facebook doc the User Taggable Friend node was **deprecated** on April 4th, 2018 and now returns an empty data set. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user-taggable-friend/